# Spring RedisTemplate : Serialise multiple Model classes into JSON.Need to use Multiple RedisTemplates?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, redis

I am using Spring Redis support to save my objects in Redis.

I have several DAOs which handle different Model classes:

For example, `ShopperHistoryDao` save/retrieve objects of `ShopperHistoryModel`, `ShopperItemHistoryDao` save/retrieve objects of `ItemHistoryModel`.

I want to use `JacksonJsonRedisSerializer` to serialise/deserialize my objects to/from json.

But in the constructor of JacksonJsonRedisSerializer, it takes one specific Model class.

```
JacksonJsonRedisSerializer(Class<T> type)
```

Does that mean, I have to configure separate `RedisTemplates` for each different Model class and use them in appropriate DAO implementation?

Something like:

```
<bean id="redisTemplateForShopperHistoryModel" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean id="redisJsonSerializer" 
                        class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JacksonJsonRedisSerializer">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="ShopperHistoryModel.class"/>
        </bean>   
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="redisTemplateForItemHistoryModel" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean id="redisJsonSerializer" 
                        class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JacksonJsonRedisSerializer">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="ItemHistoryModel.class"/>
        </bean>   
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: old, but maybe one can extend `redisJson Serializer` and make the use of `fasterxml.jackson` in order to make it more generic. i.e not forcing it to be bound to a single class definition?

Answer (score 25):

[GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.html) should do the job

```
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());                                           
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

This will add **@Class** property to the JSON to understand the type, which helps Jackson to deserialize, so no need to explicitly map the model on the configuration class.

```
"{\"@class\":\"com.prnv.model.WhitePaper\",\"title\":\"Hey\",\"author\":{\"@class\":\"com.prnv.model.Author\",\"name\":\"Hello\"},\"description\":\"Description\"}"
```

In the service you can cache the model using

```
    @Cacheable(value = "whitePaper", key = "#title")
    public WhitePaper findWhitePaperByTitle(String title) 
    {
        WhitePaper whitePaper = repository.findByTitle(title);
        return whitePaper;
    }
```

Check this article: http://blog.pranavek.com/2016/12/25/integrating-redis-with-spring-application

Comment: what about public List<WhitePaper> findWhitePapersByTitle(String title) ??

Comment: Can you share the source code ?
Am getting the following error "Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type "

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the [`RedisTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-keyvalue/docs/1.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/data/keyvalue/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html) seems to be designed to have a single instance of the value serializer.

I was going to suggest the possible workaround of having a `RedisSerializer` which contains a Map of inner serializers so you can use one `RedisTemplate` with a serializer that can handle multiple types - but since `RedisSerializer` does not offer methods like `boolean canDeserialize(..)` (as the HTTP MessageConverters in Spring MVC have) this doesn't seem possible.

So it seems that you are stuck with having multiple `RedisTemplate` instances.

Answer (score -1):

A bit of old thread, but you can do something like this:

```
<bean id="RedisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="valueSerializer">
        <bean id="jackson2JsonRedisSerializer" 
                        class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="Object.class" />
        </bean>   
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your Java class

```
@Autowire
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

public void save(Model model) {
    ObjectMapper obmap = new ObjectMapper();
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll(mode.getId(), obmap.convertValue(model, Map.class));
}
```

Comment: This is an manual to get as string then convert it using an ObjectMapper. You can benefit from Redis serializer like above answer